# Cannot get TP_LINK / TL-WN823N / Realtek 8192cu usb wireless adapter to be utilized on Debian Wheezy

Tags: wifi, networkmanager, wlan, realtek, usb-device

I have a TP-LINK TL-WN823N wireless usb stick (Realtek Module 8192cu) for my desktop. I cannot get the network manager to use it.

`Wicd` says no wireless networks found and the standard network monitor says wireless is disconnected.. I have executed the instructions at `https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x`. At the bottom I have the contents of the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and have run `apt-get update`.(while performing these tests the computer was connected through the ethernet cable)

from looking at `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig wlan1`:

```
wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:e9:84:16:63:ed  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

`ifup wlan1`:

```
Ignoring unknown interface wlan1=wlan1.
```

output from `lsb_release -a` for the OS version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy)
Release:    7.9
Codename:   wheezy
```

relevant output from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
```

The output from `apt-cache search Realtek`:

```
flashrom - Identify, read, write, erase, and verify BIOS/ROM/flash chips
nictools-pci - Diagnostic tools for many PCI ethernet cards
firmware-realtek - Binary firmware for Realtek wired and wireless network adapters
```

From doing, `apt-get install firmware-realtek`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firmware-realtek is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

relevant output from `dmesg`:

```
[   19.751049] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   19.783738] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   19.784619] rtl8192c_common: Loading firmware file  rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
[   20.202574] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
[   20.499417] r8169 0000:02:00.0: firmware: agent loaded rtl_nic/rtl8168e-3.fw into memory
```

trying to bring the wlan0 up, with `ifconfig wlan0 up`:

```
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

but `ifconfig wlan1 up` works in that no error is presented

From looking at `lsmod | grep rtl`:

```
rtl8192cu              74897  0 
rtlwifi                81393  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        52602  1 rtl8192cu
mac80211              192806  3 rtl8192c_common,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              137243  2 mac80211,rtlwifi
usbcore               128741  5 ehci_hcd,usbhid,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
```

contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

The `/etc/apt/sources.list` contents

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.7.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20141018-13:04]/ wheezy main
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.7.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20141018-13:04]/ wheezy main
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian wheezy contrib
# Debian 7 "Wheezy"
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the configuration file in `wicd` to direct it to `wlan1`, since it is being registered but not seen.

```
sudo nano /etc/wicd/manager-settings.conf
```

and set instead of `wlan0` or `none`

```
wireless_interface = wlan1
```